# How to write store procedure with unknown number of parameters?

Tags: sql

I am trying to write sp which will get different number of parameters but every time some of the parameters have value and others are null.

This sp is written to search in db and return back result based on variant  number of parameters (variation of parameters mean variation of fields to be considered).

Comment: depends on you u can use a formatted xml as input then read this xml n  do the required  sql

Comment: Use default values.

Comment: In Postgres you can use a `variadic` parameter. Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Tis is what I have done in past where parameters are dynamic I create a xml in C# and passed that xml in proc . In the proc I read that xml and then based on the XML values you can write the query . please note yo have to update the proc for each new parameters you add later to make your query working correctly

```
    DECLARE @FileXML XML = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Parameters>
       <Parameter name  ="para1" value="1"/>
        <Parameter name  ="para2" value="4"/>

    </Parameters>';

    --CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ParseDynamicXML
    --   @XML XML
    --AS
    BEGIN

      SELECT 
        Parameters.value('@name','NVARCHAR(100)') AS name,
        Parameters.value('@value','NVARCHAR(100)') AS value


        FROM @FileXML.nodes('Parameters/Parameter')Catalog(Parameters)

    RETURN;
    END;
```